# How to configure POJO so it index integer value as text instead of integer?

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to load data in apache solr using code. Being relatively new to this i wrote the following Code to load the data but when i see the data in solr it has indexed the integer values on integer which it should do by default i want it to be indexed as text. How i can do the same?

```
public class ARHts {

    @Field("section")
    private String section;
    @Field("hts_no")
    private String hsNo;
    @Field("description")
    private String description;
}
```

here hts_no is getting indexed as integer i want it to be indexed as text.

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually have to do that on the server side (might differ in some larger implementations, I'm not sure what the spring-boot-implementation allows) by defining the field `hts_no` as a string field (or as a text field if you want to do non-exact searches as well) before starting to index your content.

You can [use the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/schema-api.html) to define a field and its type:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name": "hts_no",
     "type": "string",
     "stored": true, 
     "indexed": true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/schema
```

.. or you can [use the older `schema.xml` configuration](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/defining-fields.html) (be aware that this may have been copied over to `managed-schema`).

```
<field name="hts_no" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```